# JQuery UI - Add dblclick Event to Modal dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI to generate modal dialogs.
I generate them after clicking a div.
The problem is adding a dblclick event on the title bar span after generating it. The ID got set automatically and I'm trying to add the event by this code after generating them:

```
$("div").find('span#ui-id-1.ui-dialog-title').on('dblclick', function () {
            alert("test");
        });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, but it works when I execute it using the debug console whyever.

[HTML Code on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afjrc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this:

```
$("body").on('dblclick', 'span#ui-id-1.ui-dialog-title', function () {
```

because modals are dynamically created so, event has to be delegated to the static parent or to the `$(document)/$('body')`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work now :)! I've used the body now.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be better to ask here or make a new question, but I want to change height and width of the dialog and it has no ID, only the title bar. Can I add one somehow? I can't use the classes as they're at many dialogs the same.

Comment: Yes you can just add width/height in the options params.

Comment: check this: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width same way you can add height also.

Comment: It worked, I had posted the comment before seeing your one with the link. Thank you very much :)